# Best way to continuously monitor a MSMQ queue in WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading, msmq

I need my WPF exe to start monitoring a queue as soon as it starts up, and then respond to messages as they come in.

The way I have it now is:

```
public partial class App
    {

        readonly BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            _worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            _worker.RunWorkerAsync();

        }

        void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            _worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
           //do work
        }
```

Obviously, this is pretty pathetic IMO.

Also, I don't like the approach of using `while(true)`, inside the thread to keep it running indefinitely..

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to read the messages from queue not permanently but periodically.
The common approach for this is using timer. For example, System.Threading.Timer.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private System.Threading.Timer _msmqReadTimer;

    public App()
    {
        _msmqReadTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(MsmqReadTimerTick);
        _msmqReadTimer.Change(0, 1000); // call MsmqReadTimerTick immediatelly and each 1000 ms
    }

    private void MsmqReadTimerTick(object state)
    {
        // do work

        // if you want to update some UI components after work, you should post this to UI thread dispatcher:
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(()=> 
        {
            // logic for updating UI should be here
        }, 
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the timer is even worse than what I have already,  The mq.Receive() method waits for the message in each loop iteration